# Why is 'to pronouncing' correct?

Tags: word-usage

Why is

> 'What's the trick to pronounce the French?'

wrong? Why is

> 'What's the trick to pronouncing the French'

correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I wrote, "What's the trick to pronounce the French?" Grammarly says I should use "pronouncing" instead of "pronounce". I think "pronounce" is a verb and pronouncing is a noun, so "pronounce" is better than pronouncing.

Comment: Yes, but it should be _pronouncing French_, not _the_ French!

Comment: Imho this use of the construction ***the trick to X*** (where ***X*** is some desired outcome) is inherently "slangy", so it's more likely to be used by speakers who either don't know or don't care which verb form to use if ***X*** is some kind of "verb-based noun phrase" (as opposed to the simple noun in *Attention to detail is the trick to **success***). But *in principle*, any verb-based clause should be the same as in *the **way** to **do** it*. And native speakers *don't* say *the way to **doing** it*, so they shouldn't use ***-ing*** after ***trick***. But - slangy usage, sloppy syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase “the trick to” takes a gerund, so it is correct to say “the trick to [doing something].” This may appear confusing because “to” usually forms an infinitive; however, like in “looking forward to [gerund],” this is not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

The set phrase **the trick to** is common in informal, spoken English but, as this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20trick%20to%20get%2C%20the%20trick%20to%20getting&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20trick%20to%20get%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20trick%20to%20getting%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20trick%20to%20get%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20trick%20to%20getting%3B%2Cc0) shows, it only started to be used in written English relatively recently: it's difficult to find actual instances from before 1980, and it only started to become common after 2000.

The NGram graph also shows that there are two possible ways to use it:

- **to** can be an infinitive marker, and so it is followed by an infinitive (get)
- **to** can be a preposition meaning "in connection with", and so it is followed by a gerund (getting).

Examples of both usages appear in the definition of **trick** in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trick) and, as the NGram graph shows, it's too early to say whether there is enough difference in the usage figures to suggest that one is favoured over the other. As such, I think that Grammarly is mistaken in suggesting that the infinitive form is not correct.

Answer (score -3):

Once you know the trick, you can continuously pronounce French and so the continuous tense is most common idiomatically.  If it’s something you only need to know once, ‘what’s the trick to unlock this door’ would also be acceptable, but less common.